# Drop-down options change based on selection

Tags: visualforce, dependent-picklist

I have a requirement where I need to have 3 dropdown and when I click USA, In the second dropdown I need to have relevant District Options and when I select Any particualt District I need to get respective Territories.

Please advice me the model and what I need to do to achieve this.

Comment: Dependent Picklists? [About](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_about_dependent_fields.htm) and [Defining Dependent Picklists](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm)

Comment: Three level dependent picklist would do for you

Comment: country will be controlling field for district and for Territories district will be controlling field

Comment: @mast0r - could you write up an answer around dependent picklists?

Comment: @metadaddy Done!

Comment: Thanks for reply. Any idea without dependent picklist because every time I get new record, I need to associate that record value in field dependency to include value.

Answer (score 2):

For this approach you need to use a standard feature of salesforce called **[dependent picklists](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_about_dependent_fields.htm)**.

> A dependent picklist is a custom or multi-select picklist for which
>   the valid values depend on the value of another field, called the
>   controlling field. Controlling fields can be any picklist (with at
>   least one and fewer than 300 values) or checkbox field on the same
>   record.

[To define dependent picklists:](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm) open your object settings page: click Create -> Objects, and select one of the custom objects in the list:

[image]

Scroll down to the "*Custom Fields & Relationships*" section and click the "*Field Dependencies*" button:

[image]

Then click on "*New*" and use the [field dependency matrix](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_using_the_field_dependency_matrix.htm) to specify the dependent picklist values:

[image]

Then save your settings and you're done!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to manually include values using dependent picklist which i dont want to do. Is there any ways where we can get dynamically , May be using schema for country,region,district and territory as Different SObjects